# Locate sql file in my computer to upload to remote database using mysql commands?

Tags: terminal, mysql

In a Mac I open the Terminal and type this command to connect to a remote database:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -h hostDb -u userDb -p nameDb
```

I get the connection and then I need to add a table loading a .sql file located in my computer.

I'm already connected to the remote database but what is the command to load **mySql.sql** ? The file path is `/Documents/mySql.sql`.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Can you not use something like mysqldump to get a text file version of your DB you want to move?

Comment: What I did in PhpMyAdmin was to export my DB to a sql file by going to Export , then select SQL and got the sql file. That's is why I need to upload this file. Can I use mysqldump in PhpMyAdmin? how?

Comment: phpmyadmin probably used mysqldump to get you that file. That's fine, you got what you need. The answer given by "Somebody still uses you.." below will do ya..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -h hostDb -u userDb -p nameDb < /Documents/mySql.sql
```

Don't know if it's going to work since it's a remote database, but to "load" an sql into your database using the command line tools, this is the way to do it.

Comment: I found this single command line to make both: dump the local database and upload to remote database: (only problem is that I can't use SSH) **/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump -u root --password=root --host=localhost -C dbname | ssh tastique@tastique.org "mysql -u my_username --password=my_password database_name"**. I tried it and the local dumping works fine.